# undefined is appending in top of documnet

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Trying to create a page using Javascript. when I try to append HTML into the main div I can see the HTML but I'm seeing undefined in the first line of the document.

````
const letterArry = [
  { name: 'A', id: 'a', soundtype: 'one' },
  { name: 'B', id: 'b', soundtype: 'two' }
];

let eleOne = document.getElementById('app');

eleOne.innerHTML = letterArry.map((i) => {
  let html;
  return (html += `<div class={alphabets}>
                      <ul>
                          <li id= ${i.id}>
                              ${i.name} ${i.soundtype} 
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                  </div`);
})```


All I'm trying to do is create a list item, I don't have any console logs in the file or browser.


can someone please help to understand why I'm seeing undefined in the top line? 

[code snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jfz9dk?file=index.js)
````

Comment: You haven't assigned any value to `html`, so the initial value for it is `undefined`. Then you use `+=` on it with a string on the right-hand side, so `+` is string concatenation. So it converts the `undefined` to `"undefined"` and appends the right-hand side to it. There's no reason for the `html` variable in that function at all, just return the string you have after `+=`.

Comment: You're not creating a list item. You're creating a new div with a new list with one item on each iteration. `map` also returns an array so you need to join up the results at some point.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Thank you so much for explaining, now I understand how it's working. Thanks a lot. I was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems.

1. map function returns an array, so instead of an html string, you have an array at the end.
2. Since you create html variable inside the map function, you don't concatinate anything. Everytime you have a new html variable with no value.

What you want can be done by map function, but reduce function suits better.

```
eleOne.innerHTML = letterArry.reduce(
  (previous, current) => previous + makeString(current), ''
);

const makeString = (current) => {
  return `<div class={alphabets}><ul>
    <li id= ${current.id}>${current.name} ${current.soundtype}</li>
  </ul></div>`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a function that maps over your data to create an array of list items (which you then `join` into an HTML string), and then you can add the result of calling that function to a `ul` element.

```js
const arr=[{name:"A",id:"a",soundtype:"one"},{name:"B",id:"b",soundtype:"two"}];

const eleOne = document.getElementById('app');

function getItems(arr) {
  return arr.map(obj => {
    return `
      <li id= ${obj.id}>
        ${obj.name} ${obj.soundtype} 
      </li>`;
  }).join('');
}

eleOne.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<ul>${getItems(arr)}</ul>`);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Answer (score -1):

return value directly HTML at start is undefined like this

```
const letterArry = [
  { name: 'A', id: 'a', soundtype: 'one' },
  { name: 'B', id: 'b', soundtype: 'two' },
];

let eleOne = document.getElementById('app');


eleOne.innerHTML = letterArry.map((i) => {
  return (`<div class={alphabets}>
                      <ul>
                          <li id= ${i.id}>
                              ${i.name} ${i.soundtype} 
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                  </div`);
});
```

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: yes i have tested this